# mongoose/mongodb query multiple sort

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

i'm quite new to mongodb. i manage to get a basic idea of a simple sort based only 1 parameter. what if there are more than 2 sort parameters. for instance, in a database made up of woodworking projects that have attributes `totalCuttingTime` and `favorited`.

Is the following a correct mongoose/mongodb function to find a list of projects that have the `least` totalCuttingTime and order in according to  `highest` favoriteCounts to lowest.

`var ProjectModel= mongoose.model('Project', schema);`

```
exports.getMinCuttingTime = function(number, callback){ 
    var leastCutTimeResult = ProjectModel.find().sort({totalCuttingTime: 1}).select({_id: 1}).limit(number).exec(
            function(err, projects) {
                callback(null, projects)
            }
        );

    var result = leastCutTimeResult.find().sort({favoriteCount: -1}).select({_id: 1}).limit(number).exec(
            function(err, projects) {
                callback(null, projects)
            }
        ); 

    return result;
}
```

Comment: it is correct. Sort by two fields in Mongo is the same as doing order by A, B in SQL query.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky and is the syntax correct? where `ProjectModel` comes from `mongoose.model('Project, schema)`

Comment: sorry, can't tell you - I was commenting on the approach being correct - selecting the smallest value for totalCuttingTime and then selecting and sorting by another value all documents which have that totalCuttingTime.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You need to put both `sort` terms into one object:

```
exports.getMinCuttingTime = function(number, callback){ 
    ProjectModel.find()
        .sort({totalCuttingTime: 1, favoriteCount: -1})
        .select({_id: 1})
        .limit(number)
        .exec(
            function(err, projects) {
                callback(null, projects)
            }
        );
};
```

It's worth noting that the ECMA-262 standard on which Node.js is based doesn't specify that an object's property order is maintained, and it's only a de facto standard to match insertion order. To eliminate any doubt, you can use an array instead:

```
.sort([['totalCuttingTime', 1], ['favoriteCount', -1]])
```

Comment: Given that object keys in JavaScript are technically unordered, is this guaranteed to sort by `totalCuttingTime` first, followed by `favouriteCount`?

Comment: @JohnnyHK I have been looking for a documentation on sort Mongoose and MongoDb, both define sort(<Object, String>) [Mongoose Query#sort](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort). Any link defining the sort with array definition ?

Comment: @pravin The native driver [docs for `Cursor#sort`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#sort) include the array style.

Comment: This being a nodejs specific feature should have been included in the mongoose docs.. Not sure why its not included.. anyways thank you

Comment: Apparently sorting by array is no longer possible; either an object or string is required. Not clear if order is preserved when passing an object, but seems to be when passing a string: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort