# are the following mongodb queries equivalent?

Tags: mongodb

so i have the below query that does NOT return anything when it should.

```
db.food.find({ingredient : {name : {$ne : "Kahlua"}}});  //empty data
```

However, what i think is its equivalent does output the correct info:

```
db.food.find({"ingredient.name" : {$ne : "Kahlua"}});   //gives correct data
```

I tried this using the [BrowserShell](http://try.mongodb.org/) for the above 2 queries, and it hasn't given me much problem for simple functions and queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

```
db.food.find({"ingredient.name" : {$ne : "Kahlua"}});
```

is saying "find where the ingredient name is not equal to Kahlua", whereas...

```
db.food.find({ingredient : {name : {$ne : "Kahlua"}}});
```

is saying "find where the ingredient sub object consists of a name property only, where that name is not equal to Kahlua". So in this case you're actually performing a search on the whole subject.

Probably far better explained here - [dot notation vs subobjects](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29#DotNotation%28ReachingintoObjects%29-DotNotationvs.Subobjects)

Comment: would you be able to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567953/mongoose-mongodb-query-multiple-sort