# Sorting a collection in MongoDB with multiple keys

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, sorting, sql-order-by

I'm learning MongoDB and I found to sort a MongoDB collection you have to do something like:

```
db.people.find().sort({firstname: 1, lastname: 1})
```

This should correspond to `ORDER BY firstname, lastname` in SQL. In order to `ORDER BY lastname, firstname`, you have to use:

```
db.people.find().sort({lastname: 1, firstname: 1})
```

Note that `{lastname: 1, firstname: 1}` is a JSON object. So that seems the key order matters here. But from my understanding the keys of a JSON object should not take any significance. Where is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to sort by multiple fields:

```
db.people.find().sort([
  ["firstname": 1],
  ["lastname": 1]
]);
```

Here, we can also use objects instead of arrays. But the order of sort may or may not be as specified. But in case of Arrays, it will be.

Comment: Your statement is not correct. As stated in MongoDB's documentation: Applications can issue queries that return results sorted first by ascending username values and then by descending (i.e. more recent to last) date values, such as:
`db.events.find().sort( { username: 1, date: -1 } )`

Comment: Please have a look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567953/mongoose-mongodb-query-multiple-sort

Comment: Haha, thank you! That answer is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: This doesn't work for Older Versions of MongoDB though. I got an error `"Can't canonicalize query: BadValue bad order array [2]"` on MongoDB 2.6.4.  But it worked when I ran it on MongoDB 3.2